# Confusion with the notation via Schwinger bosonic representation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, notation, quantum-optics, lie-algebra

There is a known $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ bosonic representation, called [Schwinger bosonic representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_map). In this notation, according to the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_map), the angular momentum state $|j, m\rangle$, where $j = 0, 1/2, 1, ...$, and $-j \leqslant m \leqslant j$ corresponds to the bosonic number Fock state $|k, n\rangle$ as follows
\begin{equation} \label{1}
|j, m\rangle= \left( \frac{a_{1}^{\dagger k} a_{2}^{\dagger n}}{\sqrt{k ! n !}}|0,0\rangle = |k, n\rangle \right)=\frac{a_{1}^{\dagger(j+m)} a_{2}^{\dagger(j-m)}}{\sqrt{(j+m) !(j-m) !}}|0,0\rangle , \tag{1}
\end{equation}
i.e. putting: $j = (k+n)/2$, $m = (k-n)/2$. But one can reverse the last correspondence (let's say, make a map from the angular momentum space to the bosonic Fock space back) and obtain: $k = j+m$, $n = j-m$.

Thus, formally, $|k, n\rangle \rightarrow |j+m, j-m\rangle$. So, shouldn't it be the state $|j+m, j-m\rangle$ in the LHS of \eqref{1}, instead of $|j, m\rangle$ ? Or it's just a renaming and it should be something like $|j^{\,'}, m^{'}\rangle = |j+m, j-m\rangle$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a question about notation. In Wikipedia, the notation $|j,m\rangle$ is chosen to write states using their $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ representation labels. You could choose a different notation $\widetilde{|k,n\rangle}$ that labels states by number operators of the two oscillators. Then $\widetilde{|k,n\rangle} = |\tfrac{k+n}{2},\tfrac{k-n}{2}\rangle$, or $|j,m\rangle = \widetilde{|j+m,j-m\rangle}$. They are just two ways to write the same state. If you want to use both, make sure to clearly distinguish between the two notations!

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your “error” is in using an equal sign $\vert j,m\rangle=\vert k,n\rangle$, as this implies $j=k$ and $m=n$, which is incorrect.

A more appropriate notation would be
$$
\vert k,n\rangle \mapsto \vert jm\rangle
$$
so as to make it clear this is a map and not an equality.  Under this map, $$
j=(k+n)/2\, , \qquad m=(k-n)/2 \, ,\tag{1}
$$
and the last two *are* equalities.

The map of course also works in the other direction: $\vert jm\rangle\mapsto \vert n_1 n_2\rangle$ where you can just invert (1) to get $n_1,n_2$ in terms of $j,m$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.